# getClientConnection() method deprecated in jpp6

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jppf

```
private JPPFClient client;
JPPFClientConnectionImpl connection = (JPPFClientConnectionImpl) client.getClientConnection();
```

In JPPF3 this code working without any issue.

But in JPPF6, `getClientConnection()` is deprecated and replace with below method with arguments.

```
getClientConnection(final int priority, final JPPFClientConnectionStatus...statuses)
```

I don't have any idea what to add in this arguments.

Tried google and check related classes in jar to get idea what to add in this arguments.

`JPPFClientConnectionStatus` is an enum type and there are lot of constants in that class. Can anyone tell what to add in this arguments?